# Query for substrings from freeform STT input

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, search

I have a PostgreSQL database with vocabulary in a table.

I want to receive Speech to Text (STT) input and query my vocabulary table for matches.

This is tricky since STT is somewhat free-form.

Let's say the table contains the following vocabulary and phrases:

- How are you?
- Hi
- Nice to meet you
- Hill
- Nice

And the user is prompted to speak: `"Hi, nice to meet you"`

I transcribe their input as it comes in as `"Hi nice to meet you"` and query my database for individual vocabulary matches. I want to return:

```
[
   {
     id: 2,
     word: "Hi"
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     word: "Nice to meet you"
   }
]
```

I could query with wildcards `where word ilike '%${term}%` but then I'd need to pass in the correct substring so it'd find the match, e.g., `where word ilike '%Hi%`, but this may incorrectly return `Hill`. I could also split the spoken input by space, giving me `["Hi", "nice", "to", "meet", you"]`, and loop through each word looking for a match, but this may return `Nice` rather than the phrase `Nice to meet you`.

**Q: How can I correctly pass substrings to a query and return accurate results for free-form speech?**

Answer (score 1):

1. Two PostgreSQL functions could help you here:

- `to_tsvector`: creates a text search list of tokens (lexemes: unit of lexical meaning)
- `to_tsquery` for querying the vector for occurrences of certain words or phrases.

  See [Mastering PostgreSQL Tools: Full-Text Search and Phrase Search](https://compose.com/articles/mastering-postgresql-tools-full-text-search-and-phrase-search/)

2. If that's not enough you need to turn to natural language processing (NLP).
   Something like [PyTextRank](https://github.com/DerwenAI/pytextrank) could help (something that goes beyond the bag-of-words technique):

   ```
   import spacy
    import pytextrank

    text = "Hi, how are you?"

    # load a spaCy model, depending on language, scale, etc.
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

    # add PyTextRank to the spaCy pipeline
    tr = pytextrank.TextRank()
    nlp.add_pipe(tr.PipelineComponent, name="textrank", last=True)

    doc = nlp(text)

    # examine the top-ranked phrases in the document
    for p in doc._.phrases:
        print("{:.4f} {:5d}  {}".format(p.rank, p.count, p.text))
        print(p.chunks)
   ```